# error on querying nested model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

My models:

```
OrderStatus 
  belongs_to Order

Order
  has_one OrderStatus
  belongs_to Logo

Logo
  has_many Orders
```

I would like to perform a query on Logo model attribute named artwork:

`OrderStatus.includes({:order => :logo}).where(:order => {:logo => {:artwork => search_artwork}})`

but it basically throws an error:

`SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: order.logo: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "order_statuses"."id") FROM "order_statuses" LEFT OUTER JOIN "orders" ON "orders"."id" = "order_statuses"."order_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "logos" ON "logos"."id" = "orders"."logo_id" WHERE "order"."logo" = '---
:artwork: xxxxxxx'`

I can't see the reason of this error.

**EDIT**

After extensive searching I realised that where part should be using table names (that is, plurals), so my code should be

`@order_statuses = OrderStatus.includes(:order => [:logo]).where(:orders => {:logos => {:artwork => search_artwork}})`

but I still see the SQLite3 exception error

`SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: orders.logos: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "order_statuses"."id") FROM "order_statuses" LEFT OUTER JOIN "orders" ON "orders"."id" = "order_statuses"."order_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "logos" ON "logos"."id" = "orders"."logo_id" WHERE "orders"."logos" = '---
:artwork: xxxxxxxx
'`

Comment: Does your "orders" table have a "logos" column?  What are the attributes on your "orders" model according to your db/schema.rb?

Comment: create_table "orders", force: true do |t|  
    ...  
    t.integer  "logo_id"  
    ...  end

Answer (score 0):

So the quick answer to

> I still see the SQLite3 exception error ... `no such column: orders.logos`"

Is that your `orders` table doesn't have a column named `logos`, it has a column named `logo_id`, which was created in your migration you mentioned in your comment.

The reason this error is happening is that Rails doesn't understand (as far as I know) nested values in a `.where` clause.

---

Perhaps more importantly, I think what you're (probably) more interested in is:

- how do I write logic that will give me all the `OrderStatus` records related to the `Logo` with an `artwork` value equal to `search_artwork`?

If so, adding a `has_one :through` relationship to your `Logo` model will make this really easy!

```
OrderStatus 
  belongs_to Order

Order
  has_one OrderStatus
  belongs_to Logo

Logo
  has_many Orders
  has_many OrderStatuses, :through => :Order # This is what you're adding!
```

Then, your query should be as simple as:

<s>Logo.where(artwork: search_artwork).includes(:orderStatus)</s>

EDIT: oops the above is wrong

```
Logo.where(artwork: search_artwork).order_statuses
```

For more information on Rails relationships and using `has_many :through`, see:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: you may be just right that `where` can only accept one level of nesting. I don't see anywhere in the docs examples with more than one level.    However, your solution is not what I am trying to achieve - you will get a instance of Logo model, where I need all instances of order_statuses of Logo with given `artwork`

Comment: ah you are correct, my bad!  I've edited the post to update the syntax of the command to return a collection of OrderStatus rather than the Logo model

Comment: that almost worked. Unfortunately, `Logo.where(artwork: search_artwork)` will return a *relation* which doesn't have a `order_statuses` method. But, if I look for a Logo object instance with `Logo.find_by(artwork: search_artwork)`, I can get all order_statuses by calling `.order_statuses` on it.    Anyway, thanks for your good suggestion, it pointed me in a new direction.